# MongoDB data/db not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I do gave this path for data/db

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.2.6/data/db
```

The following step was made in order to create a bound to mongodb folder

```
sudo mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.2.6/data/db --logpath /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.2.6/log/mongodb.log --logappend -rest
```

When initialize sudo mongod in terminal the following error appears:

```
2016-06-08T14:45:06.970+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8107 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=iMac-Krystyna-2.local
2016-06-08T14:45:06.970+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.6
2016-06-08T14:45:06.970+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25
2016-06-08T14:45:06.970+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
2016-06-08T14:45:06.970+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-06-08T14:45:06.970+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-06-08T14:45:06.970+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-06-08T14:45:06.970+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-06-08T14:45:06.970+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-06-08T14:45:06.970+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-06-08T14:45:06.970+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2016-06-08T14:45:06.970+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Can you please explain what is wrong and maybe show some common practice in order to work correctly with MongoDB?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to create this directory as root

Either you need to use sudo , e.g. `sudo mkdir -p /data/db`

Or you need to do su - to become superuser, and then create the directory with `mkdir -p /data/db`

Comment: On Mac OS Big Sur, the command `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` produces the error: `mkdir: /data/db: Read-only file system`.

Comment: should mongodb user have access to `/data/db`?

Answer (score 13):

You can also give this command `sudo mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb`.
Open another terminal and run your *mongod*.

Comment: thank youuuu so much

Answer (score 9):

It worked for me.
try: `sudo service mongod start`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. This worked for me:

```sh
sudo mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, an incorrect conf file caused Mongo to use default settings (i.e. using `/data/db` as the storage path. Because `/data/db` doesn't exist, it complains.

Possible sources of incorrect config include:

(1) Unquoted strings. E.g. storage.dbPath should be `"some/path"`
(2) Incorrect bindIp. It seems an array of IPs is not supported.

So my fix was simply to use quoted strings in those places:
    storage:
      dbPath: "/some/path"
    net:
      bindIp: "127.0.0.1"

Note: My `"/some/path"` has permissions drwxr-xr-x (755) and is owned by mongodb/mongodb. And it works.

Answer (score -3):

`MongoDB` try to find data/db folder under root directory of your system. try to create folder under /data/db.